# Unable to run ionic app on Android emulator - [error] ADBs is unresponsive after 5000ms

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to run an ionic/angular app locally using an Android emulator.

I receive the error below when using "ionic capacitor run android".

Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]